# Из какого пространства имен Autofac взят метод

Tags: c#, autofac

Есть такой код.

```
  public class CalculationModule : Module
  {
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
      //
    }
  }
```

Скажите пожалста метод Load() взят [отсюда](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/9B1ECC6F.htm)  или [отсюда](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/A4220791.htm) ?? . . . и как это определяется ??

Comment: Ваш класс унаследован от класса `Module`, значит вы перегружаете метод `Load` класса `Module`.

Comment: спасибо большое